# Modeling and Insurance probability question.

Tags: probability

In modeling the number of health insurance claims ﬁled by an individual during a three year period, an analyst makes a simplifying assumption that for all non-negative integer up to 5,
$p_{n+1} =\frac{1}{2}p_n$
where $p_n$ denotes the probability that a health insurance policy holder ﬁles n claims during this period. The analyst assumes that no individual ﬁles more than 5 claims in this period. Under these assumptions, what is the probability that a policy holder ﬁles more than two claims in this period?.

Comment: I get $\frac19$.  It would help if you'd post your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability series from $0$ to $5$ claims will be:
$\frac{32}{63}, \frac{16}{63}, \frac{8}{63}, \frac{4}{63}, \frac{2}{63}, \frac{1}{63}$ which sums to $1$ and for $1$ to $5$ claims each is one half of the previous probability.
For claims greater than two:
$p(n>2) = \frac{4}{63}+\frac{2}{63}+\frac{1}{63}$

$ = \frac{1}{9}$

Comment: I made a mistake.  Yeah it is $\frac{1}{9}$ Thank you